# Does block indentation cause errors?

Tags: haskell, indentation

I'm working on a nim game in Haskell and run into a problem when I tried to implement a way to choose when the human player can make a move

The code works as it should, but only for human players. The problem is that when the computer ai is supposed to make a move. I therefore have to create an if to check who's turn it is.

I have not yet implemented the ai, but the goal is to get the ai to make a move when player == 2, or by using an else for the `if player == 1 then`

This is the code that runs my game:

```
-- To run the game
play :: Board -> Int -> IO ()
play board player =
   do newline
      putBoard board 1
      if finished board then
         do newline
            putStr "Player "
            putStr (show (next player))
            putStrLn " wins!"
      else
        if player == 1 then
            do newLine
               putStr "Player "
               putStrLn (show player)
               row <- getDigit "Enter a row number: "
               num <- getDigit "Stars to remove: "
               if valid board row num then
                 play (move board row num) (next player)
               else
                  do newline
                     putStrLn "That move is not valid, try again!"
                     play board player

nim :: Int -> IO ()
nim x = play (initial x) 1
```

The players are given an int at the start of the game (`player`). What I aim to achieve is that the function give the human player the move when this variable is equal to 1 (it changes every turn between 1 and 2). This is the error code I'm getting:

```
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
    |
124 | nim :: Int -> IO ()
    | ^
```

This error did not pop up before I added the `if player == 1 then` line.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You wrote an `if` (in `if player == 1`) without an `else`. Haskell does not have an `if .. then ..`, only an `if .. then .. else ..`, since an expression is supposed to always return something. That being said, please do *not* use `IO` blocks for non-io logic.

Comment: Indentation does not cause errors. Improper *use* of indentation does.

Comment: Some of the most common misunderstandings seem present in this question.  See https://wiki.haskell.org/Common_Misunderstandings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `if` needs an `else`... including your `if player == 1`.

That said, I'd recommend two things:

1. Use a custom type that has just the right values, instead of `Int` which has way too many values.
2. Use `case` instead of `if`.

Like this:

```
data Player = Human | AI

play :: Board -> Player -> IO ()
play board player = do
    newline
    putBoard board player
    case (finished board, player) of
        (True, _) -> do
            newline
            putStrLn $ "Player " ++ show (next player) ++ " wins!"
        (_, Human) -> do
            newline
            row <- getDigit "Enter a row number: "
            {- ... etc. -}
        _ -> {- compute a move -}
```